I want to find an example of a finitely generated right module $M$ over $R$ such that $Hom_R(M, R)$ is not a finitely generated left module over $R$
Let $R$ be a ring with unity. If $M$ is a finitely generated right module over $R$, can we conclude that $\text{Hom}_R(M, R)$ is a finitely generated left module over $R$?
In other words, I want to find an example of a finitely generated right module $M$ over $R$ such that $\text{Hom}_R(M, R)$ is not a finitely generated left module over $R$.
